# Smart pointer usage when creating thread

Tags: c++, reference, thread-safety, shared-ptr

## Problem Description

I have encountered compiling error when developing C++ program using `std::thread()`, I have solved this problem by myself, but I haven't found out the reason yet.

Given the complexity of C++ code, it may not be easy for everyone to understand the source code directly(triton backend), so I simplified my code structure as follows:

```cpp
void main_func()
{
    std::map<int, int>* requests_map = {};
    
    SortInput(requests_map);    // This function will change the value of requests_map
                                // I'm pretty sure this function will not cause the compiling error.
    Execute(requests_map, input_tensors);   // input_tensor comes from other place.
                                            // this variable will not cause the compiling error.
}

// the implement of Execute function (simplified):
void Execute(std::map<int, int>* requests_info, 
             std::shared_ptr<std::unordered_map<std::string, Tensor>> input_tensors)
{
    
    // create the shared pointer here.
    auto requests_info_ptr = std::make_shared<std::map<int, int>(*requests_info);
    
    // create a thread and execute the forward function.
    my_thread = std::thread(ThreadForward, &input_tensors, &requests_info_ptr);

    my_thread.join();
}

// the implement of ThreadForward (simplified):
int ThreadForward(std::shared_ptr<std::unordered_map<std::string, Tensor>>* input_tensors,
                  std::shared_ptr<std::map<int, int>>* requests_info)
{
    // process logic
}
```

just compile the code above, I encountered compiling error:

```
error: static assertion failed: std::thread arguments must be invocable after conversion to rvalues
  120 |           typename decay<_Args>::type...>::value,
      |                                            ^~~~~
```

Then I doubted if it was the smart pointer initializing problem:

**Should I initialize the smart pointer outside the `Execute` function instead of initializing it inside?**

Then I modified my code as follows:

```cpp
void main_func()
{
    // I just initialize it here.
    auto requests_map = std::make_shared<std::map<int, int>>();
    
    SortInput(requests_map);    
    
    Execute(requests_map, input_tensors);   // input_tensor comes from other place.
                                            // this variable will not cause the compiling error.
}

// the implement of Execute function (simplified):
void Execute(std::shared_ptr<std::map<int, int>> requests_info, 
             std::shared_ptr<std::unordered_map<std::string, Tensor>> input_tensors)
{
    
    // do nothing here because the function has got shared_ptr from parameters.
    
    // create a thread and execute the forward function.
    // just directly pass in
    my_thread = std::thread(ThreadForward, &input_tensors, &requests_info);

    my_thread.join();
}

// the implement of ThreadForward (simplified):
int ThreadForward(std::shared_ptr<std::unordered_map<std::string, Tensor>>* input_tensors,
                  std::shared_ptr<std::map<int, int>>* requests_info)
{
    // process logic
}
```

**and bug fixed, no more compiling error.**

## A pointer to `shared_ptr`?

To be honest, this is a code snippets of NVIDIA Triton Backend, as you can see the `input_tensor`, using a pointer to `shared_ptr` when designing the `ThreadForward` function. I have no idea why they designed the parameters like this.

But it worked. Also when I modified my code in their way, my code worked, too.

## Unknown problem

I just wonder how this worked? Why raw pointer not work while shared_ptr worked? What about the `static assertion failed` error?

Problem solved, not know the reason yet.

Hope some experienced C++ developers can help me with it.

:)

Comment: aside from a few typos, both snippets should work just fine, i am guessing your example fails to capture the issue that originally caused your first snippet to not compile.

Comment: also this is calling the copy constructor of `std::map` which is very expensive `auto requests_info_ptr = std::make_shared<std::map<int, int>>(*requests_info);`

Comment: Passing pointers to function-local variables to a new thread is a recipe for disaster.  You're vastly over-using pointers in situations where they are both unhelpful and dangerous.

Comment: Why are mixing raw pointers at all? Even `shared_ptr` is an overkill; You don't need them either; just create values. Then use value-capture lambda with `std::move`: `std::jthread {{[tensors=std::move(tensors_input), request=std::move(request_info)]{/*async logic*/}};`. `jthread` gets you rid of the final `join` that you missed in the code.

Comment: The `input_tensor` processing logic was the original code of triton, after I realized my different pattern in using pointer, I just changed the raw pointer to shared pointer to pass in, and the code work.

Comment: I forgot to add the `join()` in the posted code, edited.

Comment: "and bug fixed, no more compiling error" - The absence of compiler errors in *no way* means that the code is bug free or that a bug was fixed. It  *only* means that the code is syntactically valid - nothing more.

Comment: @JesperJuhl you are right, I run my program and found some problems, then I debug for a while. It works well and no bug.